# Unexpected negative edge weight error in boost::prim_minimum_spanning_tree

Tags: c++, boost-graph

The following code throws "negative edge weight" on `prim_minimum_spanning_tree`call even though i am using *only* positive numbers. What should be changed to make it work?

```
typedef boost::property<vertex_distance_t, int> VertexProperty;
typedef boost::property<edge_weight_t, int> EdgeProperty;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty> Graph;

typedef pair<int, int> Edge;

Edge edges[] =      {Edge(0, 1), Edge(1, 2)};
int weights[] =     {2, 1}; // this works: int weights[] =   {1, 2}; 

Graph g(edges, edges + sizeof(edges)/sizeof(Edge), weights, 3);
std::vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> predecessors(num_vertices(g));
boost::prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, &predecessors[0]);
```

Note: I can make it succeed by tweaking weight values.

Compiler : MS Visual Studio 2010 C++
Boost version: 1.54

Comment: It doesn't seem like they would be, but perhaps the weights are cumulative, so any descent in weight would mean an edge had negative weight? Obvious test: does it always succeed if the weights are ascending, and always fail if they're descending values?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Yes, it is sensitive to the ordering. Since the above code works correctly with boost ver 1.53 I tend to beleive it is a bug in the latest boost version (1.54).

Comment: @alexm I see that you have already [reported the bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9012), and it has been fixed (incredibly fast!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [Boost bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9012), and is already fixed: if anyone else sees this behavior from 1.54, just [update to 1.55 or newer](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html).