# Kruskal Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: c++, boost, cgal

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to run CGAL (version 4.5 beta1) with Boost Graph Library (version 1.54) Kruskal Minimum Spanning Tree with my input. The code is exactly in this url: https://doc.cgal.org/4.2/CGAL.CGAL.CGAL-and-the-Boost-Graph-Library/html/BGL_triangulation_2_2emst_8cpp-example.html

My input is

```
0. 0.
1. 1.
0. 2.
1. 0.
```

But when I run it, the output is not nice. This is the output of edges in minimum spanning tree (EMST). Each line is an edge which is a pair of points.

```
(0 6.95331e-310) - (0 0)
(1 1) - (1 0)
(1 1) - (0 2)
```

However, when I print the Delaunay Triangulation, the output is as expected.

```
(0 0) - (0 2)
(0 0) - (1 1)
(1 1) - (0 2)
(1 1) - (1 0)
(0 0) - (1 0)
```

I think it should be (0,0) in the first line in output of EMST. Moreover, I think the EMST should contain `(0 0) - (1 0)` rather than `(0 0) - (0 0)`. I don't know the root cause and how to fix this problem.

Comment: What version of boost are you using? What version of CGAL are you using?

Comment: Sorry for missing information. I just edited my post above. I'm using Ubuntu, CGAL 4.5 beta1, Boost 1.54.

Comment: I get this with libcgal4.2-5ubuntu1 and boost1.54: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8637717/ (could be invalid input, or debug checks disabled in your build?)

Comment: I didn't install cgal with ubuntu repo. I installed cgal 4.5 beta manually by downloading, make and make install. Everything is fine, no error, no exception, just that the outcome is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I quote [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791402/1728537):

> This was a [Boost bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9012), and is already fixed: if anyone else sees
>   this behavior from 1.54, just [update to 1.55 or newer](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html).